# having trouble with SDL 2.03 and VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, sdl, sdl-2

Ok so recently I'v made the jump from VS 2013 to VS 2015 and I wanted to start a new SDL project I followed the steps on [here](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/index.php) to the letter and for some reason I get these linker errors whenever I try to compile my code.

**error 1:**

Warning LNK4098 defaultlib 'msvcrt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library SDLtutorial c:\Users\Nas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SDLtutorial\SDLtutorial\MSVCRTD.lib(initializers.obj)    1

**error 2:**

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__fprintf referenced in function _ShowError SDLtutorial c:\Users\Nas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SDLtutorial\SDLtutorial\sdl2main.lib(SDL_windows_main.obj)   1

**error 3:**

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func referenced in function _ShowError  SDLtutorial c:\Users\Nas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SDLtutorial\SDLtutorial\sdl2main.lib(SDL_windows_main.obj)   1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like SDL was compiled with a different version of Visual Studio (probably VS2013). You should either make sure that you're using the correct version of SDL's .lib file for your version of Visual Studio, or grab the Source Code from SDL and compile a library yourself.

Also, error 1 can be safely ignored most of the time.

Comment: yea after reading the SDL wiki it looks like SDL 2 doesnt support VS 2015

Comment: I would still try downloading the source code + project files, since you can almost always compile a library yourself for VS2015 with minimal changes to the solution.